# Best Feature Extraction Practise for Long Audio Data

Tags: feature-extraction, audio-recognition, features

I have a video dataset and my aim is classifying predefined scenes in these videos at 1fps (that means I perform classification at each second). Therefore, I plan to fuse audio and visual features for classification.

In the audio feature extraction part, I'd like to learn what is the best way for feature extraction when working with very long data. An audio channel extracted from a video length is typically between 0.5-3 hours. I thought about following options:

1. Chunk audio into 1 second windows and use Wav2vec2.0 model
2. Chunk audio into 10 seconds windows, use Wav2vec2.0 model, and decrease output shape with conv layers to a shape corresponds to 1 seconds
3. Use Wav2vec2.0 with largest possible audio input and chunk output with the shape corresponds to 1 second
4. Compute spectrogram/MFCC and chunk 1 second windows

My biggest concern is preserving temporal information because it is important for me to use past information for classification at the current time step. Thus, options 1 and 4 looks not ideal to me but I feel that these are most natural approaches and I haven't seen any example using options 2 and 3.

And finally, should chunking (windowing) operation be done with rectangular window or hann/hamming window? Would it make any difference in this case?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How long a context window is needed to perform the task with the desired performance? How much does a human need?

Comment: did you ever find an answer to your question? If yes, can you please share? I am dealing with a similar problem.